# My Sql Server database connection is not getting error

Tags: vb.net

Do I have to add connection string somewhere else  like we do in web config in Asp.net but in vb.net windows form I can't find anything like web config
Below is code for connection...

```
 Dim Conn As New SqlConnection
    Conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Abc;Initial Catalog=Test_Database;Integrated Security=True"
    Conn = New SqlConnection
    ' If Conn Is Nothing Then
    If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        MsgBox("Connected")
    Else
        MsgBox("Not Connected")
```

Comment: In your project you should have an _app.config_ file. That's the file to use

Comment: I am using Vb.net 2015 for windows form. Where can I find app.config file?

Comment: In your solution explorer, it should be the 4th item in the list.

Comment: I don't see any :(

Comment: Then Add it - Add New Item, General, Application Configuration File. You can use the same ConnectionStrings section that you can see in a web.config

Comment: I created one as you said but still same error

Answer (score 2):

It is not working, because you are 'Newing' the SqlConnection after assigning the connection string.

THis is your current code;

```
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection
    Conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Abc;Initial Catalog=Test_Database;Integrated Security=True"
    Conn = New SqlConnection
    ' If Conn Is Nothing Then
    If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        MsgBox("Connected")
    Else
        MsgBox("Not Connected")
```

However you have to take out the second new for the connection string, should look like this;

```
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection
Conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Abc;Initial Catalog=Test_Database;Integrated Security=True"

' If Conn Is Nothing Then
If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    MsgBox("Connected")
Else
    MsgBox("Not Connected")
```

Comment: Now I got new error..Can not open System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:Login fail for user

Comment: What kind of database are you trying to connect to? Would it be SQL server? Error points that it is trying to connect, but it can not log in to the server. Have a look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/ the site list the proper connection string to various database types.